# How to GZIP all the files or a list of files from some path?

Tags: gzip

I know that gzip compress a file, but I would want to know. How to compress a list of files, each file in their own GZIP file ?

I need to use the list of a folder: ls *log.2011*
And for each file create a zipped file.

Any ideas ?

Comment: So your file *log.2011* lists compressed files? You want them all compressed as a single archive right? I'd look at using *tar*.

Comment: do you have a bunch of folders with x amount of files in and you want a zip for each folder? because multiple files requires tar aswell.

Answer (score 20):

`gzip` will always compress each file into a single .gz file when given a list of files on its command line.

For example

```
$ gzip -r log.2011
```

to recursively walk the log.2011 directory and compress all files it finds, or

```
$ gzip log.2011/*
```

to compress only the files in the log.2011 directory without descending into subdirectories.

Answer (score 3):

This will output a gz archive for each matching file, files are replaced by the archive:

```
gzip fileprefix*
```

Have a look to the '-r' flag too.